# Place figures after evoking the figure* environment using fixltx2e

Tags: floats

I know there is a couple of questions about placing figures, tables, floats in general as in, e.g., [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned).

But my question is different. I am using the IEEEtran template. In the middle of the text I evoked the `figure*` environment because the figure that I have in hands is to big for just a column. However, that figure is shifted to the next page. Nothing wrong with that.

After doing that, I used the `figure` environment to place another figure. This new figure will appear after the last one. However, I think it looks better before the previous one (in previous page), otherwise there will be much text between the place that I want it to appear and the actual placement.

I noticed this only happens because I am using also the fixltx2e. The logical solutions would be to comment the `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` line or using the `[H]` from the float package. However, I am wondering if there is a better (clever) way to do this, while keeping the benefits of fixltx2e.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\begin{figure*}
    \caption{fig1}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure*}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \caption{fig2}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \caption{fig3}
    \label{fig3}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: If you dont use fixltx2e the floats will be numbered out of order, if you want the single column float to appear before the double you really want it to have a lower number so the easiest thing is to move it forward in the source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach to these problems is to save the 'old' definitions of macros that are changed by loading the offending package, and then restore the old versions after `\usepackage`. The [fixltx2e package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) changes nine macros which affect double column float placement. This example changes them back.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter
\let\old@dblfloatplacement\@dblfloatplacement
\let\old@end@dblfloat\end@dblfloat
\let\old@doclearpage\@doclearpage
\let\old@startdblcolumn\@startdblcolumn
\let\old@addtonextcol\@addtonextcol
\let\old@addtodblcol\@addtodblcol
\let\old@addtocurcol\@addtocurcol
\let\old@xtryfc\@xtryfc
\let\old@ztryfc\@ztryfc
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\let\@dblfloatplacement\old@dblfloatplacement
\let\end@dblfloat\old@end@dblfloat
\let\@doclearpage\old@doclearpage
\let\@startdblcolumn\old@startdblcolumn
\let\@addtonextcol\old@addtonextcol
\let\@addtodblcol\old@addtodblcol
\let\@addtocurcol\old@addtocurcol
\let\@xtryfc\old@xtryfc
\let\@ztryfc\old@ztryfc
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\begin{figure*}
\rule{0.9\textwidth}{20pt}
    \caption{fig1}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure*}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\rule{0.45\textwidth}{20pt}
    \caption{fig2}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It should be noted that the float placement code in `LaTeX` is rather complex, so I can't be certain that this won't have an adverse effect on something else. In fact I wouldn't be surprised if either egreg or David Carlisle were to show up shortly and point out that this hack is a complete disaster.

Comment: _I_ wouldn't be so rude:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- Well I wouldn't take offense anyway; I'm perfectly happy to admit that I don't understand the code for `fixltx2e`, so I shouldn't really be hacking it.